# How to add local jar into maven repository?

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for my Java projects. And i am working with the maven plugin. I havent installed maven locally. How to import local jar into the maven repository, without installing maven locally!

**Update**: I found this asked question: [How to add local jar files in maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project) But it assumes that maven is installed locally.

Comment: You assumed correctly, why don't you simply install maven?

Comment: what's the end use case? you don't need jars installed locally if maven is not installed locally anyway

Comment: OP might not have admin permission to install software on their computer. If that is the case, you can still get maven [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). Download the binary zip and extract.

Comment: I hoped there is some way to do this just with the plugin.

Comment: but the plugin is most probably using an embedded maven installation anyway, so you are falling on the initial case anyway

Comment: Use dependency tag in pom.xml to describe jar file and push jar file into respective folder (artifacts and version described in pom.xml) inside .m2 directory. .m2 will be in your Users/home directory.

Comment: try the solution suggested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38339518/5606016) answer then, you can run the `pom.xml` file via Netbeans then (again, it will use maven anyway, embedded or installed). Still think you question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank u very much to pointing me to that answer! It works for me! I havent to install maven locally!